# apt-get behind a proxy with authentication

Tags: bash, proxy

I have a very weird problem.I am in an university and we are supposed to connect to this proxy server.And everytime we connect we are supposed to enter our username and passwrod(LDAP).Here starts the problem.My password has a '@' symbol in it.And when I modify the/etc/apt/apt.conf it looks something like this

Acquire::http::proxy "http://:xx@xxxx@10.1.9.36:8080/"

where xx@xxxx is the password...but obviously this is not right! 
It tries to connect to the url after the first @..i.e xxxx@10.1.9.36

What am I doing wrong here..

Comment: and how is this related to programming?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and have no idea what are the rules and customs here! Have I tagged it wrongly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try URL encoding your password's @ sign?

@ == %40